# Map over Axios Response and append 2nd Axios Response to 1st

Tags: reactjs, axios, es6-promise, react-hooks

I'm creating a movie search React App using `axios` and the TMDb API. I want to make an `axios.get` call to search for a movie based on `query`, then map over the response, and pass the `movie.id` for each movie into a 2nd `axios` call to get more details for each movie.

I have tried many approaches, but I'm confused about how I need to return the values, or if I need to use async/await at some point in the code to wait for responses. I don't really know the best way to go about this - there's got to be a simple way to do it in sequence, but the asynchronous nature of the problem makes this difficult for me.

I thought it would be simpler to make my first axios call inside my search function, and then write a second function `getDetails(id)` that takes a movie id and makes an axios call with it.

Ideally, if I call the getDetails function in a map, get a response, append that response to my movies array, I could easily have an array of movies with appended details to each individual movie. I could then store the entire array in state, and use a single piece of state to manage all my movie data. I know that this process is not synchronous and that axios is promise based, but is there a way to go about this sequentially or am I approaching it all wrong? I know that `.push()` is not working in this situation, but I have tried other methods and they have always returned undefined, a promise, or an unintended result.

```
 const search = query => {
    axios
      .get(
        `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&query=${query}&page=1&include_adult=false`
      )
      .then(response => {
        response.data.results.map(movie => {
          const details = getDetails(movie.id);
          return movie.push(details);
        });
      });
  };

  const getDetails = id => {
    axios
      .get(
        `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${id}?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US`
      )
      .then(response => {
        return response.data;
      });
  };
```

**EDIT 1:** I've played with the answer by Abanoub Istfanous, and it seemed to return undefined with the added dispatch to update my state. I tweaked it more and the second set of code marked WORKING seems to be displaying some search results, but I cannot render any of the appended data from `getDetails` to the screen, as they are showing undefined. Am I still doing something incorrectly?

**NOT WORKING:**

```
  const search = async query => {
    dispatch({
      type: MOVIE_SEARCH_REQUEST
    });
    const response = await axios.get(
      `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&query=${query}&page=1&include_adult=false`
    );

    const data = Promise.all(
      response.data.results.map(async movie => {
        movie.details = await getDetails(movie.id);
      })
    );

    dispatch({
      type: MOVIE_SEARCH_COMPLETE,
      payload: data
    });
    return data;
  };

// getDetails is unchanged...
```

**WORKING:**

```
  const search = async query => {
    dispatch({
      type: MOVIE_SEARCH_REQUEST
    });
    const response = await axios.get(
      `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&query=${query}&page=1&include_adult=false`
    );

    const data = Promise.all(
      response.data.results.map(async movie => {
        movie.details = await getDetails(movie.id);
      })
    );

    dispatch({
      type: MOVIE_SEARCH_COMPLETE,
      payload: response.data.results
    });
    return data;
  };

// getDetails is unchanged...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it returns undefined is because Promise.all() will be executed asynchronously on the job queue and will only return the result after all Javascript gets executed and the call stack gets empty. So a simple solution to your code will be placing an await before Promise.all().

```
const search = async query => {
dispatch({
  type: MOVIE_SEARCH_REQUEST
});
const response = await axios.get(
  `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&query=${query}&page=1&include_adult=false`
);

const data = await Promise.all(
  response.data.results.map(async movie => {
    movie.details = await getDetails(movie.id);
  })
);

dispatch({
  type: MOVIE_SEARCH_COMPLETE,
  payload: response.data.results
});
return data; //No need to return data since you are dispatching it to redux store
};
```

You can read more about the asynchronous nature of JS on browsers here:

https://medium.com/@Rahulx1/understanding-event-loop-call-stack-event-job-queue-in-javascript-63dcd2c71ecd

Comment: Thanks very much. Looks like it's working correctly now. I definitely have some reading to do.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use Promise

```
/*
*@return data 
*/
const getDetails = async (id) => {
    const response =  await axios
      .get(
        `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${id}?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US`
      )
      return response.data
  };
```

then

```
 const search = async (query) => {
    const response = await axios
      .get(
        `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&query=${query}&page=1&include_adult=false`
      );
const data = Promise.all(response.data.results.map(async movie => {

  movie.details = await getDetails(movie.id);
}))
return data

  };
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This was still confusing to me and after some experimentation, seemed to be returning undefined for each movie. I played with the code, because I had to put in a dispatch statement to update state. I've edited the main post with more details.